# Minimal OpenGL example in Java

Tags: java, opengl

As an Java developer, I recently had idea of learning OpenGL. I fully understand, that Java isn't best language for computer graphics, but as I just want to learn basics and concepts (and not writting Minecraft 2), I think it will do just fine.

I have started by searching in google and github for some "hello worlds" that uses JOGL (Java OpenGL). I was extremly supprised, that well above 85% of those "hello worlds" had about 100-500 lines of code (that I mostly do not understand just yet) and also, nearly none of them used Maven/Gradle dependency, which caused me must trouble with setting libraries (including native) properly (Using Linux, not sure if this is important).

I am really looking for some trivial example, like just add Maven/Gradle dependency, write simple JavaFX window, that displays OpenGL sphere, so I could focus on OpenGL instead of configuring everything.

There were few examples for Android, but I would like to run it on laptop (easier development).

Am I missing something? Where should I look for it?

Comment: "85% of those "hello worlds" had about 100-500 lines of code" - unfortunately you hardly find something shorter, OpenGL API is quite a mess. At first you should choose OpenGL version (1.x, 2.x, 3.x ...) or OpenGL ES version (1.x, 2.x, ...) which is used on mobile devices. Contemporary versions extensively use shaders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I fully understand, that Java isn't best language for computer graphics

Well, it depends, each language has its pros and vs.

For example Java allows you to get a running program very quick, but you don't have full control on the memory like c/c++.

It doesn't take time to compile and can be run even when some part of the code are full of errors.

But is getting somehow verbose compared to some newer jvm languages, such as kotlin, scala or groovy.

> I have started by searching in google and github for some "hello worlds" that uses JOGL (Java OpenGL). I was extremly supprised, that well above 85% of those "hello worlds" had about 100-500 lines of code

Well, that is because rendering is not as trivial as you thought.

However if you like to have core classes very compact you can eliminate a lot of boilerplate code  by delegating laborious and manual work to util classes and get an hello triangle below a hundred lines.

For example in this hello triangle of [mine](https://github.com/java-opengl-labs/helloTriangle/blob/master/HelloTriangle/src/gl4/helloTriangle/HelloTriangle.java). you can:

- avoid many default calls to `glWindow`  in the `main` method
- save all the constant variables in a static class
- avoid `initDebug()`
- cut down in half `initBuffers()`
- init your shader programs in one line by movind `initProgram()` to utils

> nearly none of them used Maven/Gradle dependency, which caused me must trouble with setting libraries (including native)

I feel you, I really do.

And exactly because of this, I started two organization on github, one called [java-graphic](https://github.com/java-graphics) to be API neutral and another one called [java-opengl-labs](https://github.com/java-opengl-labs) for everything related to jogamp, in order to address some major problems of us java devs and converge all our single effort into a unified place.

I wish also to have available plenty of modern tutorials, tools, libraries and whatever, all of them under Maven/Gradle dependency, one click and I get everything set it up and ready to be used.

When I started learning OpenGL the situation was much worse, I am trying to change it, but it is an huge effort.

There are a lot of things to do:

- writing new counterparts tools (major are assimp and bullet)
- improving existing code
- implementing Maven/Gradle
- writing wikis
- improving channels communications
- ...

If you (or anyone who is reading) can contribute then please, do not hesitate do that, you are very welcome :)

> I am really looking for some trivial example, like just add Maven/Gradle dependency, write simple JavaFX window, that displays OpenGL sphere, so I could focus on OpenGL instead of configuring everything.

The simplest you get, it that hello triangle I linked you. Unfortunately it has no Maven/Gradle dependency yet, but it relies only on pure jogl.

> There were few examples for Android, but I would like to run it on laptop (easier development)

Since you are also mentioning Android (and somehow also verbosity previously), let me suggest you to take a look to Kotlin... I recently started digging into it and it is a whole new level compared to java, I also wrote a small [hello triangle](https://github.com/elect86/kt/blob/master/src/hello.kt) just as a pure style exercise

Comment: Note: we tend to discourage voting commentary in either questions or answers here - put something in the comments if you must, but it is not of interest to most readers, who do not even sign in, let alone vote. Keep 'em succinct!

Comment: On a side note, downvoting probably does not reach the high bar of "hate", which is a strong word  probably reserved for war, racism, and so forth. Downvoting is merely a communication device to say that a post did not meet someone's expectations for quality, and it is best not to take it personally. Whilst one could argue that a downvote is unreasonable on a good answer, both the measure of "downvotable" and "good" are subjective. You will find that if you produce consistently good posts, you will get more points than you lose.

Comment: I said that because the question and every answer got strangely -1, without a reason, all of them relatively soon. That's why I supposed it was the same guy. Ps: I'd not compare hate with war/racism, or at least in this contest

Comment: `I'd not compare hate with war/racism, or at least in this context`. That's why I think it's the wrong word. It's a personal frustration of mine that minor misdemeanours these days are popularly referred to as being motivated by "hate", presumably so the perpetrator can be regarded as a "hater" (explicitly so in your case). This linguistic device is designed to render a person completely beyond the pale, when in fact the wrongdoing in this case was merely a triviality or a nuisance, and when we think about it, they were unlikely to have been motivated by hatred at all.

Comment: Haters, of course, can be (subconsciously) written off as unstable, nasty, malicious, not worth listening to, etc, which are not reasonable assumptions for a person who has merely clicked some buttons on a website. The misuse of language in this way, in my opinion, reduces its power for when strong terms are really appropriate. Apologies for the off-topic pondering - I think language and its usage is interesting, and is worth reflecting on.

Comment: Look halfer, honestly the reason I wrote it in the edit more than frustration (which I have no problems admitting) was mainly because I wanted to "make group" and react compact against this guy, which it kind of happened, because I +1ed OP and Darren and myself I got 2+. This made me happy because we kind of proved to be a community.
About the hate, you have valid arguments from some point of view, anyway this would lead to an interesting but exhausting discussion which unfortunately I wouldn't really do it now and here, in part because of time, tiredness and not owning english the way I want

Comment: Anyway, let me conclude that I am sorry if this caused you (and others) troubles and (crappy) work to do, it wasn't my intention. I am off, good night dear ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try taking a look at the JogAmp wiki, and the demos with available source code.

JogAmp Wiki: http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page

JogAmp Demos: http://jogamp.org/jogl-demos/www/

I would also suggest reading the [OpenGL Redbook](http://www.glprogramming.com/red/), this will introduce a lot of core OpenGL concepts, but is made for Version 1.1 of OpenGL, still a good read, but some practices will be outdated.

Lastly I'd recommend reading The OpenGL Programming Guide - 8th Edition. It's basically like the redbook but for modern OpenGL. [Here's](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321773039) a link for it on Amazon

Code from the redbook and the OpenGL programming guide are going to be in pseudo code or C/C++, but the concepts and API calls are all the same between Java and C/C++. The only major differences will be in window creation, but that should be covered in the JogAmp demos and wiki.

EDIT: I just noticed there's a 9th edition of The OpenGL Programming Guide, you may want to read that instead, the 8th edition covers OpenGL 4.3, and the 9th edition covers 4.5.

Unfortunately you won't find any simple or trivial example. Learning OpenGL is a very large undertaking, and it won't happen overnight. Learning to configure your libraries, and the core concepts of the OpenGL API will help you a lot in the long run.